# Filter out duplicates from a loaded dataset in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I'm doing some ETL in SSIS to build some dimensional data sets. One of these is a date. When generating a set of dates for the dimension I can use a lookup against what's already in the date dimension and redirect any that fail, which are assumed to be new dates and then get added to the table.

Problem is the dataset that I've got might itself contain duplicate dates. This will cause errors with unique date keys when inserting into the dimension table. So I'm looking for a way to filter within the dataset that is loaded in the SSIS pipeline.

I could use DISTINCT on the initial loading of date but the date in this case is a DATETIME. I need to use a data conversion transformation later to turn this into a DATE by just taking the date component. I'm looking for unique days and a distinct on a DATETIME won't give me that.

I can't use SSIS lookup as I have before as that requires a connection manager that points to a database.

I could tell the OLE DB destination to not use bulk insert ignore any errors. This assumes however that the only errors will be duplicate dates.

I'm pretty new to SSIS and haven't been able to find a transformation tool that will allow me to compare to other rows in the set.

Comment: Do you have access to the indexes that enforce the key?  If so, you can enable the option `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` which will just discard duplicate inserts instead of generating an error.

Comment: When you store the datetime, is the time component zeroed out or coerced to a common value? Given `2011-10-10 00:00:00.000` and `2011-10-10 12:12:12.012` the process should only send one 2011-10-10 row. Does it matter which one is selected? Can we drop the time component?

Answer (score 7):

You can either use a Sort Transformation and select remove duplicates, or you can use the Aggregate transformation and only use group by (which will be more or less like a DISTINCT). Note that these operations are async, meaning all rows must enter this task before they continue, as opposed to sync tasks that just eats and spits out buffers of rows as they come in.